# Is the verb phrase "to save face" a calque of an Asian idea?

Tags: etymology

Is the verb phrase *to save face* a calque of an Asian idea?  The reason I ask is that I'm not aware that the sense of the word *face*, as its being used there, is used with any other word than *save*, and I see it nearly always applied towards Oriental peoples.  So, then, is it a calque, a word-by-word translation of an Asian idea?  If not, the derivation seems a little mysterious to me from the ordinary sense of *face* — does anyone know if *face* in the given sense was used before sustained European contact with the East?

Comment: You can also [lose](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lose+face) face...

Comment: James Clavell had a variation I really liked (in *[Noble House](http://www.amazon.com/Noble-House-James-Clavell/dp/0385343264)*, I think):  "losing ass".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To the question whether it's a *literal* calque, the answer is **no**, at least according to the OED, since it doesn't exist a 1:1 correspondence with some Chinese expression.

The OED says that it was "*originally used by the English community in China, with reference to the continual devices among the Chinese to avoid incurring or inflicting disgrace. **The exact phrase appears not to occur in Chinese**, but ‘`to lose face`’ [tiu lien], and ‘`for the sake of his face`’, are common.*"

I couldn't find any entry for *save face* in my dictionary and, although this is not the ultimate evidence (it's a free dictionary), it matches with what the OED says and you can find further reference in the block-quote below.

Finally, for your last question, whether this expression has some references in an earlier time or not, I'll paste the particular part you need from [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Face_%28sociological_concept%29#Chinese) where there is more info, in case you want to go more in depth:

> For the earliest usage examples, the OED gives the following:
>   Save one's face is recorded in the [Westminster Gazette](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westminster_Gazette) (April 5, 1898): "*Unquestionably the process of saving one's face leads to curious results in other countries than China.*"
>
> Save-face is found in [Chambers Journal of Literature, Science and Arts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chambers_Journal_of_Literature,_Science_and_Arts) (1917): "*The civilian native staff had bolted at the first sign of trouble, 'going to report to the authorities' being their 'save face' for it!*"
>
> Face-saving first appears in Enoch A. Bennett's Lilian (1922): "She had been trapped beyond any chance of a face-saving lie."
>
> Face-saver, defined as "something that 'saves one's face', originated in [Edgar Snow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_Snow)'s Scorched Earth (1941): "*As a face-saver, however, Doihara was given enough support, from the Kwantung Army in Manchuria.*"
>
> Carr (1993:74) notes, "*It is significant that the earliest usages for English lose face, save face, save-face and face-saver refer to China, while later ones are more international in application.*"
>
> By expanding "lose face" into "save face", English developed oppositely from Chinese, which has many "lose face" collocations, but none literally meaning "save face." Yao mianzi 要面子 "eager to gain reputation; be concerned about appearances" is (Hu 1944:58) "the closest Chinese approximation" for "save face."

---

I wanted to add that the transcription *tiu lien*, is written using [Wade-Giles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wade%E2%80%93Giles), the romanization system for Chinese used for most of the 20th Century before it got replaced by Pinyin.

In Pinyin it becomes "*diū liǎn*" (it took me a bit to find out), 丢脸 in Mandarin, and it means "humiliation/to lose one's credit, face or name", i.e. *to lose face*.

Answer (score 3):

The *Oxford English Dictionary* says "face" in this sense was "Originally used by the English trading community in China" based on Chinese usage.